# WordPress thumbnails not being generated at correct size

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, attachment

I have my WordPress Media settings set [like so](http://cl.ly/JGIe/o). Based on these settings no generated thumbnail should exceed the width of 540px.

I embed an image in a post [like so](http://cl.ly/JFvr/o). I choose "Large" as a thumbnail size, which should have a restricted width of 540px.

The end result is [a thumbnail](http://www.rustyrambles.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/p1000775-1024x768.jpg) of 1024x769px. Why won't these thumbnails adhere to my Media settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably modify these settings after uploading this image.

You will find several plugins de regenerate thumbnails.

PS: this question should be moved to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thumbnails are generated when uploading media, you have to set media sizes before.